# Where can I ask questions related to Sociology?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

Apparently, there's no SE site that is specifically for Sociology or the Social Sciences in general, hence this question.

I recently asked [a question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52658/is-there-a-measure-of-social-inequality) on Economics stack exchange, summarized here:

> A measure of economic inequality in a population is the gini coefficient. 
> Is there such a measure of social inequality as well? 
> ... *more clarifications and definitions* ...

This question is sociological, and doesn't specifically relate to Economics. I had searched for a Sociology SE but didn't find one - the closest ones were Economics and Politics. However this question seemed more suitable for Economics than Politics, because it was quantitative. 
While this question has been answered to my satisfaction, I'd still like to know where to ask questions related to sociology.

On a side note, as a new user - I'd also like to know why this question of mine didn't receive any (up or down)votes or much interaction/attention in general.

Comment: It sounds like the question you asked did fine on Economics. Do you have an example of a question you'd like to ask that you don't think would be on topic there?

Comment: Not an answer, because I'm not certain of your needs, but: On our [psychology.se] stack, they have tags such as sociology, social-psychology, social-cognition, social networks, social-desirability. Worth remembering our [biology.se] stack for animal social behaviour and the evolutionary aspects of human social (and other) behaviour.

Comment: @Laurel I don't have anything specific in mind right now. Although, the question seemed quite ill-suited for economics as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently an [Anthropology and Sociology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/128069/anthropology-and-sociology) proposal on Area 51 that has lasted remarkably long. It has 22 followers, 17 example questions, and is a...

> proposed Q&A site for those interested in the study of human behavior, human cultures, societies, social patterns, social change, and the social causes and consequences of human behavior.

Not sure if your example question itself would fit precisely, but I thought it deserved mention.

Answer (score 2):

**[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) seems the most appropriate site for your question.**

Sociology itself is about the organization of people, about society. A measurement of social inequality is not only important for but largely influenced by politics. Whether or not the intention behind the question has to do with getting a better understanding of related economic rather than political issues doesn't matter.

From their [Help/On-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section:

- Matters of Policy: Central to the idea of this site are the nuts and bolts of policies introduced by governments, presumably for the welfare of their citizens.
- Questions seeking to understand the rules and processes by which policy is made in various legislatures or ruling bodies are wholly on topic.

I believe asking after (a measurement of) social inequality falls under both these categories.

The following questions seem related:

- [Is there a non-hierarchical political theory based on inequality?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12291/is-there-a-non-hierarchical-political-theory-based-on-inequality)
- [Are there substantial consensus results on the political causes and/or consequences of economic inequality in political science?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38339/are-there-substantial-consensus-results-on-the-political-causes-and-or-consequen) (focuses on the measurement of economic inequality)
- [In models of income distribution, is inequality a natural outcome?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84/in-models-of-income-distribution-is-inequality-a-natural-outcome)

---

- I also assume that [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/), [as proffered by W.O.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382201/where-can-i-ask-questions-related-to-sociology#comment1274838_382201) in the comments, is not an appropriate option.
  Apart from the presence of fitting tags not being a good measurement of the germaneness of questions on an SE site, P&N focuses on the "*[cognitive sciences](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour)*", on mental faculties.
  Your question could perhaps fall under social psychology, but I believe in that case the focus would lie more on the preconditions of social inequality, and not its (presupposed) objective measurement.
- Similarly, [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) seems unfit.
  It states in [their Help section](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that "*philosophical or ethical questions related to biology*" are off topic. While inequality as a concept might have little to do with either, any measurement will be highly influenced by both philosophy and ethics (and politics :).

Comment: Good extensive answer, IMO sociology should have its own site on the SE network.

Comment: @bad_coder I also thought that sociology should have its own site , but as I see it, there are very few sociology questions either on economics or politics. Makes me think there's not enough demand for it

Comment: @whoisit sociology is its own scientific discipline so while you would expect sites on other subjects to have an overlap you shouldn't expect them to fulfill demand. As is often the case with sociology founding a separate site would create the demand and given its transversal nature I can only expect the site could potentially become hugely popular. (Although, it would necessarily suffer from the same difficulties that philosophy.se has in balancing out professional in depth Qs and amateur speculative Qs.)