# Where could I ask a question on what effect an action has on crime rates?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would be the appropriate site, if any, for this question?

### Do signs indicating that a gun owner lives in a home increase or decrease the likelihood of a burglary?

It is fairly common in certain areas for gun owners to place signs indicating that they have guns. They range from simple "Trespassers will be shot" warnings, to more humorous messages such as "This home is secured with a high-speed wireless security system" next to a picture of a gun. Regardless, the result is that anyone near the home, including potential burglars, know that there are most likely guns inside.

This can have two effects on burglars. It could be a deterrent, due to the possibility of being shot by the homeowner. However, it could also make the home a more attractive target if the burglar is confident no one is home; guns are valuable.

Which effect is stronger? Does posting such a sign make a burglary more or less likely overall?

Comment: I don't know about on topicness but perhaps law stackexchange has users who would be familiar with such data or where to get them, so may be ask around the meta there. Or if you already have some data regarding this but want to verify its validity may be skeptics SE would be useful

Comment: @user13267 I'm quite active on Law, and I'm almost sure it would not be accepted there. Skeptics is a good suggestion; if I find any major claims, I'll probably post there. Thank you!

Comment: It's kind of a crime sociology question. There isn't really any sociology site as far as I'm aware of. politics might take it if it would be on general effects related to gun regulation. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382201/where-can-i-ask-questions-related-to-sociology